# Matlab function won't plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Trying to plot a function on matlab, however the graph comes out completely empty

```
X = linspace(-2,2);

Y = (10*exp(X./10) - 7)/(exp(X.*(33/10)));

plot(X,Y);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use element-wise operation for division:

```
Y = (10*exp(X./10) - 7)./(exp(X.*(33/10)));
```

Plotting will work fine then. The problem now is that Y is a one-element array.

I want to add here that, the only operation that should be element-wise operation is the division in the middle. The other operations don't need the '.' as the division of array by scalar as no other meaning. So, it should better be written like this:

```
Y = (10*exp(X/10) - 7)./(exp(X*(33/10)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a few points to add on to @hesham_EE's excellent answer:

- For beginners, it's best to only use * when you are doing matrix multiplication. For arithmetic and/or element-wise operations, stick with .*
- It is helpful in debugging to print the output of each row of computation, i.e. omit the semicolon. This allows you to check your syntax. In this case, you would have noticed that Y was not what you had intended it to be.

Comment: Regarding your first point - it's not a matter of "beginner" or "expert", `*` means it's a **matrix** operation (i.e. one which follows the rules of algebra) whereas `.*` is an **array** operation, which is something else (although the results _may_ be the same in certain cases). You should use what's right for your problem. See also: [Array vs. Matrix Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). Regarding your second point, in debugging it's better to do **debugging**, that is use breakpoints and inspect the memory instead of printing logs.